# Local minimum implies local convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization

Consider a real function $f$, and suppose it has a local minimum at $a\in \mathbb R$.

It typically looks like

[image]

> What hypotheses can be added to $f$ so that there is some $\epsilon >0$ such that $f$ is convex over $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ ?

The motivation for this question is intuition, but I can't find any valid criterion.

Comment: Twice continuously differentiable and $f''(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: This is true, and I'm sure you and the OP are aware of the differences between convex and strictly convex but it's still good to mention for the casual reader that one does not need to have the picture above in mind. In general, this is not the case.  Consider the simple counter-example, $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.  Obviously this is convex (not-strictly) and $every$ point is a local minimizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by the user above you certainly need more than just continuity. You also need more than differentiability since one could consider $f(x)=x^{2}(\sin(\frac{1}{x})+1)$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$ which has a local minimum at $0$ but $f$ is not convex in any neighbourhood of $0$. By changing the exponent of the power of $x$ you can show further that to obtain local convexity it is not enough to be just $C^{2}$ unless you have positive derivative at the point of the minimum. Even worse, you can have a $C^{\infty}$ function with a local minimum at $x=0$ but still not be convex in any neighbourhood of $0$ provided you don't assume that $f''(0)>0$. This is shown by the function $f(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^{2}}}(\sin(\frac{1}{x})+1)$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Please see the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908903/stable-strict-local-minimum-implies-local-convexity

Answer (score 2):

No in the continuous case, a part requiring in practice convexity. Yes in the smooth case.

In general local minima have nothing to do with convexity:

The function $\sqrt{|x|}$ has a local minimum in $0$ but it is not convex

The function $e^x$ is striclty convex everywhere but has no minimum.

On the other hand, as pointed out in comments, if $f$ is continuously differentiable at least twice, and if $f''(x)\neq 0$ at a local minimum $x$, then we have $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)>0$, which forces local convexity.

In fact, this issue is the core of the so called maximum principle which is very useful in the theory of differential equations:

Suppose $f$ is a smooth function and you are able to show that at every critical point $f''<0$. Then $f$ has no local minima. 
(Ex. $x''(t)=e^x\sin(x'(t)e^t) -1$. If $x'=0$ then $x''<0$)

Comment: Please see the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908903/stable-strict-local-minimum-implies-local-convexity